# Django - No Model matches the given query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm displaying a catalog with products, which are filtered by categories, but when attempting to call the ListView from a link in the template, it returns that No Category matches the given query.

The view:

```
class CategoryProductList(ListView):
    template_name = 'catalog/product/product_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, name=self.kwargs['category_slug'])
        return Product.objects.filter(category=self.category)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['category'] = self.category
        context['category_slug'] = self.category.slug
        return context
```

The url pattern:

```
path('catalog/<slug:category_slug>/list/', views.CategoryProductList.as_view(), name='category_product_list_table'),
```

The button that calls the ListView:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{% if category %}{% url 'catalog:category_product_list_table' category.slug %}{% else %}{% url 'catalog:product_list_table' %}{% endif %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
        <i class="uil-list-ul"></i>
        View as table
    </a>
</li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: There is no error traceback. It just displays a page saying "No Category matches the given query."

Comment: That's the only thing on the page? There's nothing in the terminal?

Comment: @KlausD. The terminal displays this: `[07/Nov/2020 02:34:50] "GET /catalog/plucked-strings/list/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1784`

Comment: You just typed `{% url 'catalog:product_list_table' %}`, but it doesn't work without category